# Using CIFAR-100 datased with VGG19 model in simple_fedavg example

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'm using the [Simple fedavg example](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/v0.19.0/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg) from the github of tensorflow federated, i was trying to change the dataset and the model, but i can't get any positive feedback, the accuracy is always at 1%.

This is the code, i just changed the model part and the dataset from the simple_fedavg example. Any idea? I tried with different optimizers, but still no luck.

```
# Copyright 2020, The TensorFlow Federated Authors.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
"""Simple FedAvg to train EMNIST.

This is intended to be a minimal stand-alone experiment script built on top of
core TFF.
"""

import collections
import functools
from absl import app
from absl import flags
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff
import random

import simple_fedavg_tf
import simple_fedavg_tff
import os

np.set_printoptions(precision=None, suppress=None)

# Training hyperparameters
flags.DEFINE_integer('total_rounds', 50, 'Number of total training rounds.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('rounds_per_eval', 1, 'How often to evaluate')
flags.DEFINE_integer('train_clients_per_round', 4,
                     'How many clients to sample per round.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('client_epochs_per_round', 5,
                     'Number of epochs in the client to take per round.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 16, 'Batch size used on the client.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('test_batch_size', 128, 'Minibatch size of test data.')

# Optimizer configuration (this defines one or more flags per optimizer).
flags.DEFINE_float('server_learning_rate', 1, 'Server learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_float('client_learning_rate', 0.0005, 'Client learning rate.')

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


def create_vgg19_model():
    model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=True,
                                        weights=None,
                                        input_shape=(32, 32, 3),
                                        classes=100)
    return model


def get_cifar100_dataset():
    cifar100_train, cifar100_test = tff.simulation.datasets.cifar100.load_data()

    def element_fn(element):
        return collections.OrderedDict(
            x=tf.expand_dims(element['image'], -1), y=element['label'])

    def preprocess_train_dataset(dataset):
        # Use buffer_size same as the maximum client dataset size,
        # 418 for Federated EMNIST
        return dataset.map(element_fn).shuffle(buffer_size=418).repeat(
            count=FLAGS.client_epochs_per_round)  # .batch(
        # FLAGS.batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

    def preprocess_test_dataset(dataset):
        return dataset.map(element_fn).batch(
            FLAGS.test_batch_size, drop_remainder=False)

    cifar100_train = cifar100_train.preprocess(preprocess_train_dataset)
    cifar100_test = preprocess_test_dataset(
        cifar100_test.create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients())
    return cifar100_train, cifar100_test

def server_optimizer_fn():
    return tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=FLAGS.server_learning_rate)

def client_optimizer_fn():
    return tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=FLAGS.client_learning_rate)


def main(argv):
    if len(argv) > 1:
        raise app.UsageError('Too many command-line arguments.')
    client_devices = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
    print(client_devices)
    server_device = tf.config.list_logical_devices('CPU')[0]
    tff.backends.native.set_local_execution_context(
        server_tf_device=server_device, client_tf_devices=client_devices)

    train_data, test_data = get_cifar100_dataset()

    def tff_model_fn():
        """Constructs a fully initialized model for use in federated averaging."""
        # keras_model = create_original_fedavg_cnn_model(only_digits=False)
        keras_model = create_vgg19_model()
        # keras_model.summary()
        loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
        return simple_fedavg_tf.KerasModelWrapper(keras_model,
                                                  test_data.element_spec, loss)

    iterative_process = simple_fedavg_tff.build_federated_averaging_process(
        tff_model_fn, tff_model_fn, tff_model_fn, tff_model_fn, server_optimizer_fn, client_optimizer_fn)
    server_state = iterative_process.initialize()

    metric = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='test_accuracy')
    model = tff_model_fn()

    for round_num in range(FLAGS.total_rounds):
        sampled_clients = np.random.choice( train_data.client_ids,  size=FLAGS.train_clients_per_round,   replace=False)
        sampled_train_data = [ train_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(client).batch( FLAGS.batch_size, drop_remainder=False)
            for client in sampled_clients
        ]

        server_state, train_metrics = iterative_process.next(
            server_state, sampled_train_data)

        print(f'Round {round_num} training loss: {train_metrics}')
        if round_num % FLAGS.rounds_per_eval == 0:
            model.from_weights(server_state.model_weights)
            accuracy = simple_fedavg_tf.keras_evaluate(model.keras_model, test_data,
                                                       metric)
            print(f'Round {round_num} validation accuracy: {accuracy * 100.0}')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```

Comment: Try to change the  `weights='imagenet'` and `the learning rate`

Comment: i tried with ```model = tf.keras.applications.VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(32, 32, 3), classes=100)```
but no luck, tried with different learning rate too

Comment: How many rounds are being trained (value of `total_rounds` flag)? The default 50 rounds maybe too few for CIFAR-100; https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.00295 trained for thousands of rounds. They also found that using adaptive optimizers (e.g. Adam) on the server had significant benefit in convergence; the code above seems to use SGD.